# Finding sum of ints in a string

Tags: c, while-loop, fgets

I need to output the sum of the numbers that are inside of a sentence.
For example :

- input: abc3x casa2 y34zq
- output : 3+2+3+4 = 12

I need to read all the sentences include the space to do this, but my loop with `getchar` doesn't work. Can help me to find the problem?

```
int main() {

    int i = 0;
    int somma = 0;
    char s[MAX];

    printf("inserisci la stringa : ");
    scanf("%s",s);

        while((s[i] = getchar()) != '\n'){
            i++;
            if(s[i]>'0' && s[i]<'9'){
            somma+= (int)s[i]-(int)'0';
        }
    }
    printf("la somma è = %d", somma);
}
```

I don’t have to use `getchar`. I would prefer to use `fgets` because I know that `fgets` can read the entire line including the space.

Comment: Why are you using both `scanf` and `getchar` on `s`?

Comment: Code you have shown doesn't compile. Please read on [ask] and provide [mcve].

Comment: scanf is used to read the senteces from the user, anche getchar i will use for to get out from the while loop. because if im using '\0' the while read only the firts senteces like : abc3x

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You don't need a getchar() there.

Comment: I only now realize that i dont hace to use getchat, i have to use FGETS! Sorry. Can you help me to use it

Comment: @umbertomauro You can directly compare `s[i]` with newline character. You already have string stored in `s[]`

Comment: Like this?  while(s[i]!=‘\n\)

Comment: Though you don't really need `getchar()` here, keep in mind that there's a reason why it returns an *int* (the reason being EOF) and you should not store it as *char* as a first order of business.

Comment: @umbertomauro Yes!

Comment: i try it but doesn't work

Comment: `if(s[i]>'0' && s[i]<'9'){` is off-by-1 at both ends.  Perhaps you wanted `if(s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9'){`?

Comment: With `fgets()`, you can read from a file and not from user at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve your problem.

1. **Get entire string in one go from user**

To read entire string, you can use `scanf` as you are using it. It will store entire string in array (`s` in your case) and then you can parse this array and peform operations as you are doing. Here limitation would be length of string. You can accept string of the `MAX` size only as your array is of that much size. If you are okay with this, then your code is correct. All you need to do is remove that `getChar()` from `while`.

2. **Read one character at a time**.

Alternatively, you can read one character at a time from user and immediately perform operations on that character. In that case, you don't need to declare array. One character variable is sufficient and you can go on accepting data from user. In this case, discard the `scanf()` and in your `while()`, accept `getChar()` output in one character and perform your operation.

P.S. There's one small bug in your while() which will give you incorrect result in few cases.

Comment: i don't wanna use getchar sorry, i edit it because i was wrong. what i wanna do is read entire sentences ! if you know how to do can you show to me the line of code. i supposed to do like printf("put the string")     scanf("%s" , s)  while ( s[i]!='\n') ...... but the condiction inside the while doesn't work !

Comment: "you can use scanf as you are using it" as in `scanf("%s",s)` is no better than `gets(s)` as they both fail to prevent buffer overrun.  Better code prevents overrun.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are ok with using [`fgets()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) you can read the entire line and then use [`isdigit()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm) to find the numbers.

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("file.txt" , "r");
if(fp == NULL) {
  perror("Error opening file");
  return(-1);
}

char line[MAX];
if( fgets(line, MAX, fp) == NULL ) { // Read entire line
    perror("Error reading file");
    return -1;
}

int sum = 0;

int len = strlen(line);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (isdigit( (unsigned char)line[i] )) { // cast handles negative values of line[i]
        sum += line[i] - '0'; // Add integer value to sum
    }
}
```

The basic idea is the same, only this loops over a string directly instead of trying to read it with `getchar()` at each step.